# Htaccess redirect match

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to do some .htaccess redirects, removing the "online" from :

`site.com/online/producator-pinguin.html` to 
`site.com/producator-pinguin.html`

I have the following .htaccess rule :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^online/producator-(.*).html$ /producator-$1.html [L,R=301]
```

This works, but the problem is that it also matches :

`site.com/online/producator-pinguin/culoare-rosu.html`

In the example, "pinguin" is a brand name, so the rule can not be hardcoded for pinguin, it should work with any word. (producator-x, producato-y, ...)

How can I rewrite the rule so it doesn't match the second example, only the first ?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^online/producator-pinguin.html$ /producator-pinguin.html [L,R=301]`?

Comment: Hello Dusan, sorry for not being clear enough :  I can't hardcode the brand name (pinguin). There are more brands, in the example the brand name is "pinguin".

Comment: `RewriteRule ^online/producator-([^/]+).html$ /producator-$1.html [L,R=301]`?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This rule does not match the url : site.com/online/producator-pinguin/culoare-rosu.html. I'll try variations of this.

Comment: But you said you don't want to match `site.com/online/producator-pinguin/culoare-rosu.html`?

Comment: Yes, it worked as expected !!! (sorry about that. Need more coffee ...)
Would you add it as an answer so I can mark it correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^online/producator-([^/]+).html$ /producator-$1.html [L,R=301]
```

The key part is `[^/]` which will prevent from matching subfolders.